# C# LINQ executing the same work over and over

Tags: c#, linq

Came across some legacy code where the logic attempts to prevent un-necessary multiple calls to an expensive query `GetStudentsOnCourse()`, but fails due to a misunderstanding of deferred execution.

```
var students = studentsToRemoveRecords.Select(x => x.CourseId)
                    .Distinct()
                    .SelectMany(c => studentRepository.GetStudentsOnCourse(c.Value));


var studentsToRemove = new List<Student>();

foreach (var record in studentsToRemoveRecords)
{
    studentsToRemove.Add(
        students.Single(s => s.Id == record.StudentId));
}
```

Here, if there are 2 records for the same course in `studentsToRemoveRecords`, the query `GetStudentsOnCourse()` will needlessly be called twice (with the same course id) instead of once.

You can solve this by converting `students` to a list beforehand and forcing it to memory (preventing the execution from being deferred). Or by simply rewriting the logic into something a bit simpler.

But I then realised I actually struggle to put into words exactly why `GetStudentsOnCourse()` is called twice in the scenario above... is it that LINQ is repeating the same work everytime `studentsToRemoveRecords` is iterated over, even though the resulting input values are identical each time?

Comment: I can't see how `GetStudentsOnCourse()` would be called more than once per course id in this query. Have you verified that this is the case?

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/PossibleMultipleEnumeration.html is what ReSharper calls it

Comment: It isn't called *twice*, it is called potentially `studentsToRemoveRecords.Count() *  studentsToRemoveRecords.Distinct().Count()`, so something lile x ^ 2

Comment: As given in the example with 2 records, it's called twice in that scenario yep - confirmed with a test

Comment: @FBryant87 Try raising the number of records...

Comment: @xanatos You're not incorrect, I'm giving an example.

Comment: @FBryant87, it is because `Single` starts enumeration every time when you call it. Enumeration == calling your method at least twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it that LINQ is repeating the same work everytime studentsToRemoveRecords is iterated over, even though the resulting input values are identical each time?

Yes, that's the nature of LINQ. Some Visual Studio Extensions, like ReSharper, give you warnings when you create code that might lead to multiple iterations of a LINQ Query.

If you want to avoid it, do this:

```
var students = studentsToRemoveRecords.Select(x => x.CourseId)
                .Distinct()
                .SelectMany(c => studentRepository.GetStudentsOnCourse(c.Value))
                .ToList();
```

With `ToList()` the Query is executed immediately and the resulting entities are stored in a `List<T>`. Now you can iterate several times over `students` without having performance issues.

Edit to include comments:

Here is a link to some good documentation about it (thank you Sergio): [LINQ Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/classification-of-standard-query-operators-by-manner-of-execution)

And some thoughts about your question how to handle this in a large code base:
Well, there are reasons for both scenarios - direct execution and storing the result into a new list, and deferred execution.
If you are familiar with SQL databases, you can think of a LINQ Query like a View or a Stored Procedure. You define what filtering/altering you want to execute on a base table to get the resulting entities. And each time you query that View/execute that Stored Procedure, it runs based on the current data in the base table.

Same for LINQ. Your Query (without `ToList()`) was just like the definition of the View. And each time you iterate over it, that definition gets executed based on the current Entities in `studentsToRemoveRecords` at that moment.
And maybe that's your intetion. Maybe you know that this base list is altering and you want to execute your query several times, expecting different results. Then do it without `ToList()`.

But when you want to execute your query only once and then expect an immutable result list over which you can iterate multiple times, do it with `ToList()`.

So both Scenarios are valid. And when you iterate only once, both scenarios are equal (disclaimer: when you iterate directly after defining the query). Maybe that's why you saw it so many times like this. It depends what you want.

Comment: Documentation to deferred and inmediate  execution methods, very useful.

https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/classification-of-standard-query-operators-by-manner-of-execution

Comment: This is actually quite a shock to me, I've clearly misunderstood a part of DE for years. So everytime we iterate over an IEnumerable, LINQ will repeat the work it performed to obtain that collection on EVERY single iteration?

How do people handle this, by adding .ToLists()'s in countless places? Thank you for opening my eyes at least, virtually every code base I've ever seen seems to have misunderstood this.

Comment: @FBryant87 I wrote some more sentences about when to use ToList and when not. Both scenarios are valid.

Answer (score 1):

Unclear exactly how your classes are done, BUT:

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class StudentCourse
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public int? CourseId { get; set; }
}

public class StudentRepository
{
    public StudentCourse[] StudentCourses = new[] 
    {
        new StudentCourse { CourseId = 1, StudentId = 100 },
        new StudentCourse { CourseId = 2, StudentId = 200 },
        new StudentCourse { CourseId = 3, StudentId = 300 },
        new StudentCourse { CourseId = 4, StudentId = 400 },
    };

    public Student[] GetStudentsOnCourse(int courseId)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(GetStudentsOnCourse)}({courseId})");
        return StudentCourses.Where(x => x.CourseId == courseId).Select(x => new Student { Id = x.StudentId }).ToArray();
    }
}
```

and then

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var studentRepository = new StudentRepository();
    var studentsToRemoveRecords = studentRepository.StudentCourses.ToArray();

    var students = studentsToRemoveRecords.Select(x => x.CourseId)
                        .Distinct()
                        .SelectMany(c => studentRepository.GetStudentsOnCourse(c.Value));
                        //.ToArray();

    var studentsToRemove = new List<Student>();

    foreach (var record in studentsToRemoveRecords)
    {
        studentsToRemove.Add(
            students.Single(s => s.Id == record.StudentId));
    }
}
```

the method is called 16 times, with `.ToArray()` it is called 4 times. Note that `.Single()` will parse the full `students` collection to check that there is a single `student` with the "right" `Id`. Compare it with `First()` that will break after finding one record with the right `Id` (10 total calls of the method). As I've said in my comment, the method is called `studentsToRemoveRecords.Count() *  studentsToRemoveRecords.Distinct().Count()`, so something like `x ^ 2`. Doing a `.ToArray()` ["memoizes"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) the result of the `GetStudentsOnCourse`.

Just out of curiosity, you can add this class to your code:

```
public static class Tools
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> DebugEnumeration<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enu)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Begin Enumeration");

        foreach (var res in enu)
        {
            yield return res;
        }
    }
}
```

and then do:

```
.SelectMany(c => studentRepository.GetStudentsOnCourse(c.Value))
.DebugEnumeration();
```

This will show you when the `SelectMany` is enumerated.